# How to view journalctl without rebooting system in RHEL 7/8?

Tags: redhat, journalctl

We're having issues with a customer having RedHat 7 PC's shutdown intermittently.

One was just sent in for repair, and I'd like to check the journald output.

However, I've read the rebooting the system overwrites it.

How can I view this journal without rebooting the system? Do I need a bootable RedHat or Centos USB stick? If so, how to I create it? How would I then view the drive/file?

Answer (score 2):

If it was shut down already, you'll have no luck. *By default*, Journald on CentOS 7/8 is storing log data in RAM.

You can [ensure Journald logs data in persistent mode](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/using-journalctl-as-the-ultimate-utility-for-troubleshooting-lemp-stacks), by simply creating `/var/log/journal`:

```
# create the directory
mkdir -p /var/log/journal
# ensure the write permissions
systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
# ping the daemon that the directory is there
killall -USR1 systemd-journald
```

This however, applies to currently booted machine and further reboots will have the data retained.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the data is stored in the `/var/log` directory. To configure the logging details see:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html

Setting `Storage=persistent` will ensure the data is written to disk.

The following values can be used to control the size limits:
`SystemMaxUse=, SystemKeepFree=, SystemMaxFileSize=, SystemMaxFiles=, RuntimeMaxUse=, RuntimeKeepFree=, RuntimeMaxFileSize=, RuntimeMaxFiles=`

Files can then be read searched using `journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the configuration file in /etc/systemd/journald.conf & make `storage=persistant` and then it will store all the logs in   `/var/log/journal`.